# Why does netbeans not sign some jars?

Tags: java, netbeans-7, jar-signing

I am having a problem with jar signing in netbeans.

I developed a component to scan images via twain directly to my web app. The component is running as an applet. During building in Netbeans the jars that are part of the project are signed ... and one of the jars, uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jar, is not signed, it is just omitted.

I am building this project as WebStart applications with my custom self signed cert, and the Netbean's build output is like that one below:

```
...
sign-jars:
Signing JAR: D:\PROJEKTY\JAVA\Scan\dist\Scan1.jar to D:\PROJEKTY\JAVA\Scan\dist\Scan1.jar as nn
Signing JAR: D:\PROJEKTY\JAVA\Scan\dist\lib\AbsoluteLayout.jar to D:\PROJEKTY\JAVA\Scan\dist\lib\AbsoluteLayout.jar as nn
Signing JAR: D:\PROJEKTY\JAVA\Scan\dist\lib\beansbinding-1.2.1.jar to D:\PROJEKTY\JAVA\Scan\dist\lib\beansbinding-1.2.1.jar as nn
Signing JAR: D:\PROJEKTY\JAVA\Scan\dist\lib\xsPDF-bin+src-20130225-2126.jar to D:\PROJEKTY\JAVA\Scan\dist\lib\xsPDF-bin+src-20130225-2126.jar as nn
generate-jnlp:
...
```

I don't understand why Netbeans is omitting just this particular jar file.
How can I force Netbeans to sign this file as well?

I am using Netbeans 7.3

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I force Netbeans to sign this file as well?

Write a custom ant task for this steps:

1. unzip to  temp directory the jar, which you want to force, like: D:\PROJEKTY\JAVA\Scan\myjarforced1
2. remove old signature, if it was
3. build a new jar
4. sign it

For me it worked ( a long time ago) in this way also you can pack all other jars into a jar. 
Some can violate licenses, but it will work the force signing.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to write custom ant tasks, yet.

However in the meantime I found the solution as well. I just changed the jar extension to zip, opened file with winrar, removed signature files, and voila, now it gets signed.

Comment: happy to help, isn't an 1 minute task, for who see the first time, here should you start: http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html . Modifying the Netbeas's build.xml and build-impl.xml you can have those tasks, on each build, what you did manually